# Get the index of the selected wxTreeCtrl item

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

In my wxpython program, I have a wxTreeCtrl that is populated from a database. This is a 'notebook' style application and I have it setup so that each note has its own unique id. In the database I'm using, there are two columns, the name and the id. What I'm looking for is to be able to populate the treectrl with the names from that database, but when the user selects one I want the event to pick up the id. I experimented with using an index based system that makes a dictionary with the index of each note as a key and the id as the value. The problem is, I can't find a way to get the index of a selected item. Looking over the [docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TreeCtrl.html), there isn't any method to do this.

Is there any method to accomplish this, or is there a better way to do this that I am overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is SetPyData(). You can call this on each tree item and attach an object to the item so you can extract additional information from the tree item.

This tutorial on the wxPython wiki does a decent job of explaining it:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/TreeControls

The relevant code is:

```
# add the child to the parent
childID = self.tree.AppendItem(parentID, child)
# associate the full child path with its tree entry
self.tree.SetPyData(childID, (child_path, False))
```